# EF Code-First Foreign Key Creating Duplicate Data

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I'm having some trouble with a Code-First ForeignKey. I have a Product as described below and I am trying to create a new LineItem with that existing Product. However when I save the changes to my context it creates an entirely new Product, but a duplicate of the one I originally used except that the id is new (new record in the db now).

Here's where I'm adding a new line item:

```
public void AddItem(Product item) {
    // checking item.Id here will return 100
    var lineItem = new LineItem
                    {
                      CartId = this.Id,
                      Product = item,
                      ProductId = item.Id,
                      Quantity = 1
                    };

    _db.LineItems.Add(lineItem);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    // checking lineItem.Id here returns 101
    // also checking item.Id here now also returns 101

    this.LineItems.Add(lineItem);
}


public class LineItem {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CartId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CartId")]
    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Why is it creating a new Product?

Comment: Where is the code that loads the product you are passing in? I expect that this instance of product is no longer attached to the context, so is being seen as a new record. As a test, leave Product = null on your new LineItem and just set ProductId.

Comment: Ahhh yes that is the problem. I was caching my products collection and using the product from that cached collection. If you make an answer I'll mark you as the answer. On a side note is there any way to use my cached version of Product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, you are using an unattached copy of your product object. So EF sees this as a new instance when it gets attached (via the generated code in the `LineItem.Product` setter and inserts it accordingly.

You can re-attach your entity like so

```
_db.Products.Attach(product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to your issue could be to pass the same context to the `AddItem` method as the one used where you've added `Products`.
This way you would be sure the the context used to `LineItems` wouldn't be detached, and EF would not see the need to add the `Products` (or any other entity for that matter) once more.

Best regards,

Adi Constantin